# How to generate an array of 1,0 with poisson distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate spiketrains with poisson distribution , its function is  `np.random.poisson()`.
but in simplest explanation how can I generate an array of 0,1 that number of 1's are 3 but size of array should be `[1,7]`

It means like this : `a=[1,0,1,0,1,0,0]....` just numbers of 1 should be distributed with poisson function in that array.

I am stuck in this problem very badly

Comment: What exactly is a spiketrain? Is your `a` array supposed to be `1` if the draw from the Poisson distribution is over some threshold?

Comment: u can consider spike train as an array of 0 , 1...just we need to say to distribute these  three 1's with poisson function in an array of 1*7

Comment: @blthayer I'm guessing it's related to modeling neural coding: https://www.cns.nyu.edu/~david/handouts/poisson.pdf

Comment: thanks for your response ...i studied this paper before but i'm stuck in coding...i just need to know how can say possion function to generate 3 ones in 3 different place of an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Z4-tier for [this link](https://www.cns.nyu.edu/~david/handouts/poisson.pdf). At the bottom of page 5, a section begins entitled "Generating Poisson Spike Trains."

Here's one possible solution:

```py
"""Generate a spike train. See page 5 and 6 here:
https://www.cns.nyu.edu/~david/handouts/poisson.pdf

This will use the first method described.
"""
import numpy as np
# Seed the generator for consistent results.
np.random.seed(42)

# We need to start with some sort of r(t). Presumably the asker of this
# question has access to this.
r = np.array([100, 500, 600, 700, 300, 200, 900])

# Define our time interval, delta t. Use one millisecond as suggested
# in the paper.
dt = 0.001

# Draw 7 random numbers on the interval [0, 1)
x = np.random.rand(7)

# Initialize output.
spikes = np.zeros_like(r)

# If x[i] <= r * dt, generate a spike.
mask = x <= r * dt

# Set to 1.
spikes[mask] = 1

print(spikes)
```

Output:

```py
[0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
```

No, this does not generate 3 spikes. Fixing the number of spikes isn't appropriate given my understanding of the paper.

Comment: @AtefehHedayati - What do you mean it isn't working for you? Is that code generating an error?

Comment: it has no error but i need to fix the number of 1's....it should be 3 not 4...i got my answer by @jonathan post ....thank you:)

Comment: @AtefehHedayati - jonathan's answer similarly does not fix the number of 1's. In his solution, to fix the number of ones you would have to both seed the random number generator *and* tweak the `expectation` input. Similarly in my answer, to fix the number of ones you have to seed the random number generator and tweak the `r` array.

Comment: yeah that's right ...the number of 1's are not fixed...i also used your code in my problem...and somehow i was wrong...since your answer was correct ...the way you said is the correct way that i can generate spikes with poisson distribution and i appreciate your help ....but @jonathan's answer  alsohelped me to range

Answer (score 0):

I would try the definition of black bars (as seen in spike trains being in used on neuron encoding) which makes you bound the limits of the function co-domain where bins is your length of 7 elements

```
    import numpy as np


    def black_bars(expectation, bins):
        poisson = np.random.poisson(expectation, bins)
        bounded_poisson = np.clip(poisson, a_min=0, a_max=1)

        print('original -> {0}'.format(poisson))
        print('bounded -> {0}'.format(bounded_poisson))


    black_bars(.5, 7)
```

output

```
    original -> [0 1 2 0 1 3 2]
    bounded -> [0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonathan ...it is exactly what i want...it helps me a lot...i needed to give a range to poisson function...thank you for your time giving to me...well done

Comment: Ow.sorry...i did it:(